How to remove the player control in media_kit flutter plugin
I want to remove the player control in media kit flutter plugin or maybe hover on the video but make it not show the control of the video. Because I try to create a custom player control on it but don't know how to hide the default control
I can only use this library and on windows only for some reason, please help!
